# click submit button redirect to index.php

Tags: php, redirect

here's my code.

```
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
  $_POST['os_number'];
  $_POST['product'];
  $_POST['quantity'];
  header('location:index.php?page=pos');
}
```

this code belongs to `pos.php` and link`(pos/index.php?page=pos)` but when I click the submit button it redirects to *index.php* with this link`(pos/index.php?os_number=1001&product=1&quantity=&add=ADD)` I wonder why. I need your help guys. it should remain in `pos/index.php?page=pos` link.

Comment: use _GET instead of _POST.

Comment: You're mixing GET with POST.

Comment: and what are these `_POST`'s doing?

Comment: Where's the HTML part?

Comment: it's just a redirect problem. the $_POST['add'] there is the name of my submitbutton. and that page is from pos.php but when I click the submit it redirects me to index.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to post your forms to `index.php` you can erase your code and use this on your html. This will redirect you to `index.php?page=pos` when click submit

```
<form action="index.php?page=pos" method="post">
    <input type = "text"    name = "os_number"/> 
    <input type = "text"    name = "product"/> 
    <input type = "text"    name = "quantity"/> 
    <input type = "submit"  name = "add" value = "ADD" /> 
</form>
```

and better you can just put `page=pos` on a hidden input

```
<input type = "hidden"  name = "page" value = "pos"/>
```

Hope this help

Comment: it's just a redirect problem. the $_POST['add'] there is the name of my submitbutton. and that page is from pos.php but when I click the submit it redirects me to index.php.

Comment: @user3113490, this should redirect you to index.php?page=pos because of the 'header' code.

Comment: yes, it should but it redirects me to index.php. I wonder what's the problem there.

Comment: can you add the html part for me to check?

Comment: <form method = "post">
 <input type = "submit" name = "add" value = "ADD" />
</form>

Comment: Where are these came from? $_POST['os_number'];
 $_POST['product'];
 $_POST['quantity'];

Comment: it's just some input. but it does not have function yet. so I didn't include it.

Comment: btw, I'm using procedural approach here.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I hope I understand you correctly.

Comment: nah I'm so stupid..hahaha I forgot to include the method = "post" in index.php file...lols my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Use `exit` after `header('location:index.php?page=pos');` line.